# PHP DOM object has some custom attributes stripped out

Tags: php, dom, hyperlink, custom-attributes

I am trying to take an entire site into a DOM object like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://thissite.com');
```

so that I can manipulate it and save a template.

However, some objects ( tags I have noticed) are stripping custom attributes out, so that:

```
<a href="/link/to/page/" aria-haspopup="true">Link Name</a>
```

changes to:

```
<a href="/link/to/page/">Link Name</a>
```

Is there any way to stop this happening?

UPDATE: Looks like this was not the issue, will leave an answer below to explain and potentially help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not a custom attribute. This custom attribute was inserted later via javascript, it was just getting the wrong link to the javascript file.

I was looking at the "inspect element" and not the page source when troubleshooting. If you have this issue, look at the original page source (not using inspect) and see if the attribute (or any difference to the original code) is different between the code in the DOMDocument (by using echo $dom->saveHTML();).

If this is the same then the DOMDocument is not the issue and you will need to check your javascript (are they relative links) etc.